# I am making a code where we create humans, make them family and print their information but I can't print it

Tags: c

Basically, I made a structure which includes informations of a person. When I create them, I then hop into my other function which should print their information but I am stuck at that point.

This is my main where I call my functions:

```
int main() 
{
    Person* p1 = person_constructor("Steven", 1970, "male");
    display_person(p1);
    return 0;
}
```

This is where I construct my human, I am required to use dynamic memory allocation:

```
Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex)
{
    Person p = {};
    Person* pptr = &p;
    strcpy(p.name, name);
    p.year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
    strcpy(p.sex, sex);
    pptr = malloc(strlen(p.name) * sizeof(char) + strlen(p.sex) * sizeof(char) + sizeof(int));
    return pptr;
}
```

And this is the print function which can't print out the name:

```
void display_person(Person* p)
{
    printf("%s",p->name);
}
```

Comment: You return freshly allocated, but uninitialized data. Allocate first, then fill the allocated memory with data. (And how you measure how much to allocate looks very suspicious.)

Comment: Do you think that `pptr` (at/after `malloc`) and `p` from `person_constructor` points to the same memory location?

Comment: It would help to see how `Person` is defined. Its definition affects the solution.

Comment: With respect to the size of the allocation, the size of a structure is not the same as the size of the sum of its member sizes, and even if it were your method would be unmaintainable if the structure had nested structures or the structures them selves were modified in maintenance.  Also note that `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition - it is never necessary to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor should allocate memory for the person object, then initialize the allocated memory, in that order:

```
Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex)
{
    Person *p = malloc(sizeof(*p));

    if (p) {
        snprintf(p->name, sizeof(p->name), "%s", name);
        p->year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
        snprintf(p->sex, sizeof(p->sex), "%s", name);
    }

    return p;
}
```

The code that calls the constructor must also free the memory after using it:

```
int main(void)
{
    Person* p1 = person_constructor("Steven", 1970, "male");

    if (p1) {
        display_person(p1);
        free(p1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Remarks:

- Allocate according to the size of your object. You don't show the definition of the person struct, but the two string fields seem to be arrays of a fixed size, so that `sizeof(struct Person)` already includes them.
- I've used `snprintf` instead of `strcpy`, becuse it ensures a null-terminated string that does not overflow the memory.

Comment: Good advice, but when submitting assignments it is probably best to stick to the taught material, so `strcpy()` may still be preferred.  Why not `strncpy()` however?

Comment: `strncpy` will not zero-terminate the string when it overflows, which may lead to surprises later. (But you are probably right that `strcpy` should be used when the course material uses it.)

Comment: In my program, I also defined significant other and children but I didnt marry my first person yet. However, the print function wont say null and will say "Child 1: DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Managemenö¿­sÖ"  this. Pretty weird

Comment: @ExperiencedSoup : Given that the code you have posted is `printf("%s",p->name);`, then clearly the code printing `"Child 1: ..."` is no longer the same.  Also the error may be down to your definition of `Person` which your question did not include M Oehm has had to make a number if assumptions here, which make sense given the code you posted, but may not be correct.  However that may warrant a different question rather then discussion in comments - we have no evidence for this new issue.

Comment: sprintf to copy the string - this is the weirdest use of sprintf I can imagine

Comment: @MOehm so see how to make strncpy safe (for example like in my answer)

Comment: @P__J__: Read again. I used `snprintf`, not `sprintf`. It has the desired behaviour and can be used out of the box.

Comment: Read again. Do you think that the sprintf with letter 'n' is not an overkill? It is very heavy slow and complicated.

Comment: @P__J__: And `strncpy`, which zeroes all bytes after the actual string, is super fast? Yes, `snprintf` needs to parse the format, but as I've said, it does what you want out of the box. Anyway, we are talking about a small buffer where handling overflow is more important than micro speed gains. (Come to think of it, I should have left `strcpy` in the code, as Clifford suggested. But then someone of the SO clientele would certainly have pointed out that my code can overflow.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `person_constructor()` is seriously confused.  You set `pptr` to point to `p`, only to overwrite it with the pointer to an uninitialised dynamic memory block (with incorrectly determined size).

```
    // Allocate the structure memory
    Person* pptr = malloc( sizeof(Person) ) ;

    // Assign the structure members
    strcpy( pptr->name, name ) ;
    pptr->year_of_birth = year_of_birth;
    strcpy( pptr->sex, sex ) ;

    // Return a pointer to the allocation
    return pptr ;
```

Comment: Note that @MOehm's answer adds safety checks that you might consider.  This answer is a bare minimum to fix your immediate problem, rather than address other potential issues not in question.

Answer (score 1):

Amended [@Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58900390/2410359) code to make it more safe, removing not needed code

```
#define some_value1 64
#define some_value2 64

typedef struct 
{
     char name[some_value1];
     char sex[some_value2];
     int  year_of_birth;
} Person;   

char *safe_strncpy(char *dest, const char *src, size_t length)
{
    strncpy(dest, src, length -1);
    dest[length - 1] = 0;
    return dest;
}

Person *person_constructor(const char *name, const int year_of_birth, const char *sex)
{
    Person *pptr;
    pptr=malloc(sizeof(*pptr));

    if(pptr)
    {
        safe_strncpy(pptr->name,name, sizeof(pptr->name));
        safe_strncpy(pptr->sex,sex, sizeof(pptr->sex));
        pptr->year_of_birth=year_of_birth;
    }

    return pptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it to:

```
//ASSUMING PERSON IS LIKE THIS:
typedef struct person
{
     char name[some_value1];
     char sex[some_value2];
     int  year_of_birth;
} Person;   


Person* person_constructor(char *name, int year_of_birth, char *sex)
{
    Person *pptr;
    pptr=malloc(sizeof(*pptr));

    memset(pptr->name,'\0',sizeof(pptr->name));
    memset(pptr->sex,'\0',sizeof(pptr->sex));

    strcpy(pptr->name,name);
    strcpy(pptr->sex,sex);
    pptr->year_of_birth=year_of_birth;

    return pptr;
}
```

Plus don't forget to check if space has been really allocated dynamically or not

Comment: what is the memset for? strcpy will add the trailing nul.

Comment: I also defined children and significant other etc. But when I am printing, like the children. It wont say null and it will print out Child 1: DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Managemenö¿­sÖ"